# What is required in Affinity Propagation

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering, text-mining

I am hoping to use **affinity propagation** to cluster my data using `sklearn`. But I came across a question whether to use a **distance matrix** or **similarity matrix** in the `fit` method.

Please let me know what is suitable to use?

Comment: Did you check the paper and the source code?

Comment: I did check the source code of sklearn. However, they are inserting some random data, so it is bit difficult to understand.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Can you please tell me if you know?

Comment: I'd have to read the paper.

Answer (score 1):

According to `sklearn.cluster.AP` (in case in `AP` chosen affinity = "precomputed") the method "fit" requires `X`  where `X` is matrix of similarities / affinities, that is, if distance matrix is estimated, use as:

`X` $ = matrix\ of\ similarities = -distance\ matrix$.